# XHR petition to Axios

Tags: javascript, api, axios, xmlhttprequest

How can i convert this simple petition to axios?.
Prints on console all the movie titles of Ghibli Studios.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest()

 request.open('GET', 'https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films', true)
 request.onload = function() {
   // Begin accessing JSON data here
   var data = JSON.parse(this.response)
 
   if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
     data.forEach(movie => {
       console.log(movie.title)
     })
   } else {
     console.log('error')
   }
 }
 
 request.send()
```

Comment: Can you show what you did so far to solve your problem?

Comment: ``` axios.get('https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/films')
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.title)
})
.catch(e => {
    console.log('error');
})```